# How to create an array that matches the students name with their score?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

void *swap(int arr[], int size);
void *swap(int arr[], int size) {
    int i,j,temp;
    
    for(int i{0}; i < size; i++) {
        for(int j{i+1}; j < size; j++) {
            if(arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }   
        }
    }
    std::cout <<"The numbers in ascending order are: ";
    for(int i{0}; i < size; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";
}

void average_score(int arr[], int size);
void average_score(int arr[], int size) {
    int average {0};
    
    for(int i{0}; i < size; i++) {
        average+=arr[i];
    }
    
    std::cout << "\nThe average is: " << average / size << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    int *test_scores = nullptr;
    int n;
    std::cout <<"Enter Size: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    
    test_scores = new int[n];
    
    int i = 0;
    int student_scores;
    
    while(i < n) {
        std::cout << "Enter Student " << i+1 << " Test Score: ";
        std::cin >> student_scores;
        
        test_scores[i] = student_scores;
        i++;
    }
    
    swap(test_scores,3);
    average_score(test_scores,3);
    
}
```

The assignment is also asking me to instead of stepping through the arrays, use pointers rather than array subscripts. I have already created a program where it takes in the test scores and calculates the average and sorts it into ascending order, now I just need to create a display of the student's name right next to their score. Any thoughts or helpful advice that I can use to help me build this program?

Comment: Simply keep that data together in a `class` or `struct` and make an array of these.

Comment: *use pointers rather than array subscripts* -- That doesn't mean you make everything you can think of a pointer.  All you have to do is instead of `array[i]` use `*(array + i)`.  Nothing more than that.  Your `swap` function shouldn't attempt to return anything, but it is declared as returning `void *`.  Not only is this wrong, you have undefined behavior going on because you don't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you have a data container called **struct** that may help you with that. (You can also use classes, but I don't think they are necessary here).

A possible struct for this problem may be declared like this:

```
struct student {
    int grade;
    string name;
};
```

In your main program you could change the test_scores array for a vector, which is more helpful as its size can be modified.

```
std::vector<student> test_scores(n);
```

If you want to access the attributes of your student struct you would do so by using the dot operator.

```
int a = test_scores[0].grade;
string s = test_scores[0].name;
```

Comment: Prefer to recommend `std::vector` rather than arrays.  Example:  `std::vector<student>`, the `std::vector` can change sizes during run-time, arrays can't.

Comment: You're right, I proposed an array as an example because of the title of the question, but definetly vectors are a better option. This is now changed.

Comment: @PereC Hey Perec I tried implementing your code but I am still a little confused. I did std::vector<student> test_scores(n) and created the struct but when I tried adding it the student_scores to test_grades by doing test_scores.push_back(student_scores) it gives me an error saying "no matching function call to std::vector<student>::push_back(&int). I am still new to this stuff so could you write the code out?

Comment: I gave you an explanation as another answer, I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You are given this error because you try to add an `int` into a `student` vector. "no matching function call" means that the compiler does not know how to transform the integer into a student. To fix it, I recommend you to ask for the name instead of only asking for the score, so you may add the following code:

```
student s;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Enter Student " << i+1 << " Name and Test Score: " << endl;
    std::cin >> s.name >> s.grade;
    
    test_scores[i] = s; // Don't use test_scores.push_back(s) here, if you do so,
    // you would increase its size by 1 and add the element s at the end of the vector.
}
```

In your average_score function, you should change the `int arr[]` parameter for a `vector <student> &arr` and `average += arr[i]` for `average += arr[i].score`. The `&` in `&arr` is important because it passes the parameter as reference so that its elements are not copied into the function, which is very unnefficient.

Your `swap` function should be `void` instead of `void *`. Also, try using the sort function of the `algorithm` library. The sorting code you implemented has quadratic cost over the vector length, which is very unefficient if you have a lot of students.

Comment: Yeah I am still having a couple of problems with my code and I think I kind of dug myself into a hole, is there any way I can send you the whole thing so you can help me fix my problem? Like email or through StackOverflow. This assignment is due tomorrow and I am kind of worried I might not finish it –

Comment: After I did everything and changed some stuff around, its now telling me that my swap function says error: no match for 'operator>' and other errors in my swap function. I even changed the parameters to std::vector<student> &arr, int size. It has something to do with my increments and arr[i] and arr[j].

Comment: You get the `no match for 'operator>'` error because you can't compare structs in C++. Your code will work if you change `if(arr[i] > arr[j])` for `if(arr[i].grade > arr[j].grade)`.

Comment: I redid everything now the only problem is when I enter a name and a number it calculates just that students name and number divided by the size of what you entered. For Instance, Lets say I entered The size of 3 and then Enter Austin, 60. It gives me 60/3 which is 20 but I don't want just my score I want everyones score for the average. I would have to rewrite my average function to comply with the std::vector<student>. Any tips?

Comment: It kind of wants it formatted on screen like for instance. Name: Austin 100 and then the word average at the bottom combining all the scores and diving it by the number of students.

Comment: If you want decimals in your average result, you should declare `float average = 0;` instead of `int average = 0`. You can reuse your `average_score` function for student vectors by changing `average += arr[i]` for `average += arr[i].score`.